# Using a single yahoo pipe as a filter for all my rss feeds

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I would like to use Yahoo Pipes to create a bunch of RSS feeds that are all filtered the same way (block is is before yesterday and limit to 25 items). This way if I ever want to change my filter, I can change my filter pipe and all of my rss feeds will automatically pick up the changes. I've put together a image that show exactly what I am trying to do:

[image: screenshot from Yahoo Pipes]

I have checked many of the stackoverflow topics and it doesn't seem to be answered if this has ever been resolved. I've also seen the [stackexchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20324/use-same-filter-for-several-pipes-on-yahoo-pipes) that seems to be asking this but doesn't get resolved in the same fashion.

Being able to do this would really improve my news reading experience and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David